# psycopg2: statement return codes

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, libpq

I have a Postgres query which I execute in Python like so

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO my_data(id, val, bonus) VALUES (1, 2, 3) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET val = ex.val;')
```

I'd like to be able to tell if a fresh insert is happening to decide some later logic on the calling side. Outside of doing an extra read before attempting the upsert, is there a way of doing this? For example, checking a return code/message on whether the conflict was triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the execute, check `cursor.rowcount` to get the number of affected rows.

If that is 1, a row was inserted. If it is 0, an existing row was updated.